# How to initialise a Realm list?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I am working through the realm swift tutorial found [here](https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/).

Once I completed the tutorial successfully on my local machine I deployed the realm object server on a Ubuntu digital ocean server.

Now when I run the code on my dev machine pointing to the server I get the error message:

```
Connecting to endpoint '139.59.102.91:80' (1/1)
2017-02-20 20:29:27.576 RealmTasksTutorial[9998:243100] Sync: Connection[1]: Failed to connect to endpoint '139.59.102.91:80': Connection refused
```

The problem, might be, that when you work through the tutorial it gets you to start up their Mac app and create a task. Then you move to the next step and create the iOS app. In the iOS app, in the SetupRealm() they synch with the realm server with the following lines:

```
if self.items.realm == nil, let list =  self.realm.objects(TaskList.self).first {
 self.items = list.items
}
```

This will only populate `self.items` if the realm server has that first task added (by the Mac app). So the tutorial works fine when all is run on my local machine.

The problem is when I deploy the realm object server to the digital ocean Ubuntu instance. There is no Mac app to populate that first task.

Is there a better way to check realm and initialize/populate `self.items`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from the port you are using.

The default configuration of the Realm Object Server runs on port `9080` for HTTP/WebSocket, and `9443` if you enable TLS. It would appear your client is trying to connect to port `80`, the default port if you don't specify anything otherwise.

Try adding `:9080` to your authentication and realm URLs.